# I want to ask how can I write this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

I'm using SQL server 2008 and I have three tables:

Table1 **Accounts**:

```
Id >> auto number
AccountId
AccountName
```

Table2 **AccountsSupport**:

```
Id >> auto number
DateFrom
DateTo
```

in this table i have one record and i will not add any records in future

Table3 **AccTransD**:

```
Id >> auto number
TransId
TransDate
AccountId
AccountName
Value
```

I want to make query like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.Id, a.AccountId, a.AccountName,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.TransDate < AccountsSuport.DateFrom THEN b.Value END) AS FirstVal, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN b.TransDate >= AccountsSuport.DateFrom AND b.TransDate <= AccountsSuport.DateTo THEN b.Value END) AS BetweenVal, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN b.TransDate > AccountsSuport.DateTo THEN b.Value END) AS LastVal, 

FROM
    dbo.Accounts AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.AccTransD AS b ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId 
GROUP BY 
    a.Id, a.AccountId, a.AccountName
ORDER BY 
    a.Id
```

Sample Data:

```
Accounts:
Id  AccountId   AccountName
1   111            CashBox
2   222            VisaBox
```

Table: TransD

```
Id  TransId    TransDate  AccountId     AccountName   Value
1     1          1/1/2017     111          cashbox     100
2     2          2/1/2017     222          visabox     200
3     2          2/2/2018     111          cashbox      50
4     7          1/1/2015     222          visabox      300
```

Table: AccountsSupport:
have one record and i will not add another one in the future
    Id  DateFrom     DateTo
    1  30/12/2016   30/12/2017

and my query should view this

```
Id  AccountId  AccountName    FirstVal   betweenVal  LastVal
1      111       CashBox         0        100           50
2      222       VisaBox         300        200           0
```

Comment: I think some sample data for these tables and your desired results would help us out a lot here. Your description of what you are looking for is not at all clear "want to write my query read the dates from my Table without writing it manual in my query" ????

Comment: Which dbms?????

Comment: thanks for your reply i want to make my query like this

SUM(CASE WHEN b.AccTransDate < (Select DateFrom From AccountsSupport) THEN b.Dp END) AS FirstDp

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Sql Server 2008

Comment: I have Change my question... and now it will be clear and thanks so much

Comment: It's still unclear. Please post sample data and expected results.

Comment: Accounts:
Id  AccountId   AccountName
1   111              CashBox
2   222             VisaBox
Table: TransD
Id  TransId    TransDate  AccountId     AccountName   Value
1     1          1/1/2017         111             cashbox             100
2     2          2/1/2017         222             visabox               200
table: AccountsSupport:
Id  DateFrom     DateTo
1  30/12/2016   30/12/2017
and my query should view this
Id  AccountId  AccountName    FirstVal   LastVal
1      111             CashBox         0            100
2      222            VisaBox          0              200

Comment: i want to Add total to values in table AccTransD as 3 Totals
Total before the dateFrom Which idefinted in AccountsSupport,
Total between the dateFrom and dateTo Which idefinted in AccountsSupport,
Total after the dateTo Which idefinted in AccountsSupport,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join to AccountsSupport.

```
SELECT 
    a.Id, a.AccountId, a.AccountName,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.TransDate < c.DateFrom THEN b.Value END) AS FirstVal, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.TransDate BETWEEN c.DateFrom AND c.DateTo THEN b.Value END) AS BetweenVal, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.TransDate > c.DateTo THEN b.Value END) AS LastVal, 

FROM
    dbo.Accounts AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.AccTransD AS b ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.AccountsSupport AS c ON TRUE
GROUP BY 
    a.Id, a.AccountId, a.AccountName, c.Id
ORDER BY 
    a.Id
```

Comment: thank you So much its useful
 but changed this dbo.AccountsSupport AS c ON TRUE
to dbo.AccountsSupport AS c ON c.Id=1 .... because i have just one rcord